# Workaround for blob as src to iframe in Edge

Tags: javascript, iframe, microsoft-edge

I've built a CodePen-like editor that's client side only. It works by letting you edit HTML, JS, and CSS, and then when you click run, it generates a blob and sets some iframe src to that blob.

This works in Firefox(49), Chrome(53), Safari(10) but it doesn't work in Edge

Is there a workaround?

I thought about using a dataURL but according to caniuse that's not supported in Edge either.

```js
var html = `
<h1>hello world</h1>
<gscript src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chroma-js/1.2.2/chroma.min.js"></gscript>
<gscript>
document.body.style.backgroundColor = chroma.hsv(Math.random() * 360 | 0, 0.4, 0.8).css();
</gscript>
`;
html = html.replace(/gscript/g, 'script');
var blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.src = blobUrl;
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

result in FF/Chrome/Safari

[image: chrome result]

result in Edge (no errors in console either)

[image: Edge result]

Comment: So I finally launched my win10 VM and yep... Edge can't `open` a blobURI... So you can't either set an iframe to a blobURI, it even fires an security error when you set the `data` of an `<object>` element (why not with iframes ? dunno...) Weirdly enough it is able to open an image contained in an iframe to a blobURI that has been created in the main page. Me don't get what they do there and I'm not going to open my VM any time soon ;-) Ps: you should undelete your answer, since it seems to be a correct workaround.

Comment: PPs: don't forget to set the `sandbox` attribute of your frame, even if Edge nor Chrome do allow the access to the parent with dataURI frames, FF does, and Chrome does with blobURIs, so I guess there is a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

2023 Now that Edge has changed to Chromium based the question is limited to any user with depreciated earlier Edge (MS have declared IE and their own earlier Edge as past end of life) here is above fiddle as seen in current MSEdge.exe

[image]

However there are differences seen between Edge on left and Firefox on right, since unspecified font defaults are at play. Verdana for Edge and Times Roman for Firefox.

[image]