# Unable to print PDF file in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, iframe, blob, microsoft-edge

Trying to print PDF file retrieved from server.

**Approach 1**

- Retrieve PDF from server via AJAX
- Create Blob (`URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile)`)
- Set blob ObjectUrl as a source to `iframe`
- Print iframe (`iframeContentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null)`)

**Problem**

Not working in Edge since it has issue [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763693/workaround-for-blob-as-src-to-iframe-in-edge), [link2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9121088/), [link3](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5411066/)

**Approach 2**

- Set URL from which server returns PDF as a source to `iframe`
- Print iframe

**Problem**

Endpoint which returns PDF requires authorization, as i see there [is no way to pass authorization information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432821/is-it-possible-to-add-request-headers-to-an-iframe-src-request), so iframe fails to load with `401 Unauthorized`.

How can i print PDF file retrieved from server in Edge ?

*Server side - ASP.NET Core*